# Curly brace expansion in zsh function?

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

I've been trying to create a function to accomplish the following and have searched SO fairly exhaustively with no results. Hopefully it's a quick solution for those well-versed in shell scripting.

I have this function in my .zshrc:

```
t() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && touch "$1"; }
```

to create the path leading to a file as well as the file itself, but I'd love for something that would work like this:

```
$ t nonexistent/path/{1,2,3}.txt
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: BTW, it's not specific to zsh that when you perform a brace expansion it generates several words (and only the first of them goes in `$1`, others ending up in `$2`, `$3`, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a loop to the function. In `zsh`, by the way, you don't need `dirname`:

```
t() {
  for d; do
    mkdir -p "$d:h" && touch "$d"
  done
}
```

You have to call `mkdir` more than is strictly necessary, but that's a small price to pay to avoid examining all the arguments to see if any of them have prefixes in common. The alternative would be to simply pass the directory and the desired files as separate arguments:

```
t() {
  mkdir -p "$1"
  shift
  push "$1" && touch "$@" && pop
}

t nonexistent/path {1,2,3}.txt
```

Actually, assuming a reasonable number of arguments, you can apply the `:h` to `$@` and let `mkdir` and `touch` do the looping.

```
t () {
  mkdir -p "$@:h"
  touch "$@"
}
```

Comment: So quick to answer. Works perfectly and thank you! Will accept the answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Performance for something like this isn't a concern of mine so I like the first version more :) But thanks for showing the alternative as well!